# How do I find sql records with certain identical attributes?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called `parents`:

```
________________________________
|childID | motherID | fatherID |
--------------------------------
|   2    |     1    |    100   |
|   3    |     2    |    101   |
|   4    |     2    |    101   |
...
```

I need to get a table returned with the `childID`s of all the children who have the same parents.

I tried

```
SELECT childID
FROM parents
GROUP BY motherID, fatherID
```

but that also is giving me children who do not have a sibling.

Comment: Which database are you using? That query is not even legal in T-SQL (SQL Server). `childID` is not an aggregate and is not one of the grouping columns.

Comment: I'm working with sqlite3

Comment: It's good to put that kind of info in the tags, so people will know.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    ChildId 
FROM
    parents p
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            motherID,
            fatherID,
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            parents
        GROUP BY
            motherID,
            fatherID
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    ) motherFatherCount
    ON p.MotherId = motherFatherCount.MotherID AND
       p.FatherId = motherFatherCount.FatherId
```